# How do load a image stored locally in byte array using FFImageLoading for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, ffimageloading

I need to be able use `FFImageLoading.ImageService` to load a byte array I decoded from an image earlier, into a `FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync` object. The method `ImageService.Instance.LoadImage(IImageLoaderTask task)` seems to be the way but I have no idea how to set up an object of that interface and I can't find any references to using this type object on the source website.

How to load a byte[] into a `ImageViewAsync` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a byte[] you could you this with the `LoadStream` method.

Something like:

```
ImageService.Instance
            .LoadStream (GetStreamFromImageByte)
            .Into (imageView);
```

And this is the method to do the actual work.

```
Task<Stream> GetStreamFromImageByte (CancellationToken ct)
{
    //Here you set your bytes[] (image)
    byte [] imageInBytes = null;

    //Since we need to return a Task<Stream> we will use a TaskCompletionSource>
    TaskCompletionSource<Stream> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream> ();

    tcs.TrySetResult (new MemoryStream (imageInBytes));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: It does not work. Could you please post a full sample? Types do not match.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it worked like this ...

Modal.cs

```
 public class User 
 {
   public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
 }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public ImageSource Avatar
{
    get  
    {
      return ImageSource.FromStream(()=> 
        {
          return new MemoryStream(this.User.Avatar);
        });
     }
}
```

View.xaml

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="userAvatar" 
 Source = "{Binding Avatar}"
    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  >

</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```