# FFImageLoading load bitmap into ImageViewAsync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-bitmap, ffimageloading

How can I load a bitmap into an ImageViewAsync on Xamarin Android Native?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do load a image stored locally in byte array using FFImageLoading for Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120859/how-do-load-a-image-stored-locally-in-byte-array-using-ffimageloading-for-xamari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LoadStream](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Android-API#stream) method, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44125190/8632294) you will see how to use this method:

```
ImageService.Instance
            .LoadStream (GetStreamFromImageByte)
            .Into (imageView);
```

Here is the `GetStreamFromImageByte`:

```
Task<Stream> GetStreamFromImageByte (CancellationToken ct)
{
    //Here you set your bytes[] (image)
    byte [] imageInBytes = null;

    //Since we need to return a Task<Stream> we will use a TaskCompletionSource>
    TaskCompletionSource<Stream> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream> ();

    tcs.TrySetResult (new MemoryStream (imageInBytes));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

About `imageInBytes`, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255501/8632294), convert the `bitmap` to `byte[]`:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
```

I have posted my demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/FFImageLoadBitmap).